# How can a graviton curve space(time) if it only couples to particles in spacetime?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, curvature, quantum-gravity

In the theory of quantum gravity (insofar it's incomplete version exists) gravitons couple to particles like photons or other gauge fields. Unlike the other gauge fields, which are vector-like or scalar-like, the graviton field is a tensor field.

Now you can see the electric field around an electric charge as a condensate of virtual photons with which other charges can couple while bringing in their own condensate.

The same happens in the graviton picture. But how does this condensate influence spacetime if gravitons couple to particles only? Is it their tensor nature? Does it "project" a metric on spacetime by being a "small packet of metric"?

Comment: Can you cite the sources talking about graviton condensates?

Comment: There is no evidence that gravitons even exist.  Back in the fraction of a second after the big bang there were quarks, gluons and gravity, that's it.